# Use EJB in XmlAdapters

Tags: java, ejb, resteasy, xmladapter

How can I inject EJBs into the XmlAdapters?

The idea is I want to get list of IDs by rest API and convert this array of IDs to List of Objects for Entity Object. For example:

```
public class Post {
    List<Category> categories;
    ...
}

public class AdaptedPost {
    List<Long> categories;
    ...
}

public class PostAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedPost, Post> {

    @EJB
    CategoryFacade categoryFacade;

    @Override
    public Post unmarshal(final AdaptedPost adaptedPost) throws Exception {
        // Use facade class to retrieve category object from ID
    }
    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support defined for injection into [javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) objects.

You will need to acquire your EJB the old fashioned way using a JNDI lookup.

Comment: Is this fast enough? Is there any other solution in my case? I mean is it good idea at all?

Comment: Do the lookup once and cache it somewhere. Alternatively, if the code has been invoked from some other EJB, inject into that one and stash it in a ThreadLocal (with the usual caveats regarding correct cleanup)